# Lazy-loading a view in a UIViewController subclass

Tags: objective-c, properties, lazy-loading

I have a UIViewController that should lazily load a view and then keep it in memory as it's re-used quite often until e.g. a memory warning occurs or I want to clean it for some other reason. In order to achieve the lazy loading, I've overwritten the default getter. Here's my code:

```
@interface MyController {
    MyView *_myView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) MyView *myView;
@end

@implementation MyController
@synthesize myView = _myView;
- (MyView *)myView {
    if(_myView == nil) {
        _myView = [[MyView alloc] init];
        // some more initialization
    }
    return _myView;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // the main part of my interest, freeing myView again
    self.myView = nil;
}
@end
```

Now my question is basically: Is it still correct to release `myView` like I did in `- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning` or would I have to `[_myView release]; _myView = nil;` or even something completely different?

Also, is this generally the correct way of using lazy initialization or should I improve something here in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement for releasing the memory is absolutely correct and there is no difference between two.

```
self.myView = nil;
```

In this case the setter method for `myView` property will be called and similar to as below.

```
-(void) setMyView:(MyView*) aMyView {
   [myView release];
   myView = aMyView;
}
```

for the lazy loading ... I guess  `-(void)viewDidDisappear` for releasing the views and others memory related stuff and `-(void) loadview` to recreate them again

Answer (score 3):

If I am not mistaken the default `UIViewController` behaviour already loads the view lazily, see [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `-loadView`:

> You should never call this method directly. The view controller calls
>   this method when the view property is requested but is currently nil.